# How to create click subcommands in python?

Tags: python-3.x, click

Having looked at the [documentation](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/commands/#) for commands and groups I did not find anything helpful for creating subcommands with click (version 7.1.2). Either I missed it or it is described in a very weird way.

What I want to do is to have a subcommand so I can do e.g.

```
python myscript.py sub1
python myscript.py sub2
```

which executes two different functions. Here is what I have tried:

```
import click

@click.group()
def sub1():
    print("sub1")

@click.group()
def sub2():
    print("sub2")
```

also I tried this:

```
import click

@click.command()
def sub1():
    print("sub1")

@click.command()
def sub2():
    print("sub2")
```

neither this works:

```
import click

@click.group()
def cli():
    print("cli")
    pass

@cli.command("sub1")
def sub1():
    print("sub1")

@cli.command("sub2")
def sub2():
    print("sub2")
```

But this does not seem to work (i.e. the print statements are never executed). How to do it right? And where exactly is this documented?

Also I get the same behavior when trying the exact given example from the documentation:

```
import click
@click.group()
@click.option('--debug/--no-debug', default=False)
def cli(debug):
    click.echo(f"Debug mode is {'on' if debug else 'off'}")

@cli.command()  # @cli, not @click!
def sync():
    click.echo('Syncing')
```

no output at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create subcommands with click, and to make it work when you call your code like

```
python mycode.py
```

you need to define the `__main__` thingy:

```
import click

@click.group()
def cli():
    pass

@cli.command("sub1")
def sub1():
    print("sub1")

@cli.command("sub2")
def sub2():
    print("sub2")

if __name__ == "__main__":
   cli()
```

They seem to have forgotten that to mention in their documentation, or it is hidden somewhere.

Comment: The `"sub1"` is not needed for `@cli.command()`, click will use the functions name if no override is given. `@cli.command()` would have the same result.